# What is coverage count and how can I build it?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

For my assignment, I am required to blend multiple square images into a single large image where each square image represents a part of the final image. To accomplish this task, I have successfully completed all necessary steps except for one.

I have been asked to provide a coverage count for the final image. However, despite searching online, I could not find any information related to this requirement. Moreover, it is not even mentioned anywhere. Although I have found something similar to it, which is called a heatmap, it is not exactly the same thing.

To provide a clearer understanding, below are the example images:

**Square images to be blended:**

[image: Square images to be blended:]

**Final image (result):**

[image: Final image (result):]

**Relative images:**

[image: Relative images:]

**Coverage map/count:**

[image: Coverage map/count:]

Comment: well, I'm not familiar with image processing to that degree, but it seems pretty intuitive that the coverage count, for each output pixel, says how many input images map to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the explanation presented in this answer, I have also initiated a thread on Stack Overflow to inquire about a certain aspect of the coverage count in my code. Furthermore, I provided an answer to the thread. For those who are interested, please find the link to the thread here: [Stack Overflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76063352/how-to-make-a-custom-color-map-in-python/76063521#76063521)

I have successfully obtained the proper definition of coverage count, which is exactly as  `Marcus Müller` had commented.

According to the definition, coverage count refers to the number of pixels that contribute to a specific area of the resulting image. This is because the pieces provided in the question overlap in certain regions, causing the value of that area to increase by one each time it is visited.

To provide further clarification, I will outline the steps I took to create the coverage count:

- Firstly, I created a `np.zeros` array with the same dimensions as the resulting image and named it `coverage_count`.
- For the initial piece, if a non-black pixel is detected at location (x, y), I added the value of that pixel at (x, y) to `coverage_count` by 1.
- For the subsequent pieces, every time two pieces are blended together, for each non-black pixel at location (x, y) in the latter piece, I added the value of that pixel at (x, y) to `coverage_count` by 1.

## Code Snippet

**Creating the coverage count:**

```
    # Create a gray coverage_count with the same dimensions as piece_1
    coverage_count = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)
    # Find the non-black pixels in piece_1
    non_black_pixels = np.any(piece_1 != [0, 0, 0], axis=-1)
    # Increment the corresponding pixels in the coverage_count
    coverage_count[non_black_pixels] += 1
```

**Building the coverage count towards the end:**

```
        non_black_pixels = np.any(later_piece != [0, 0, 0], axis=-1)
        # Increment the corresponding pixels in the coverage_count
        coverage_count[non_black_pixels] += 1
```

**Showing the final coverage count as an image:**

```
    # Normalize the coverage_count matrix to the full 8-bit grayscale range (0-255)
    coverage_count = cv2.normalize(coverage_count, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
    # Apply a colormap to the normalized grayscale coverage_count
    coverage_count = cv2.applyColorMap(coverage_count, cv2.COLORMAP_PARULA)
    # Display the colorful coverage_count image
    cv2.imshow("Coverage Count", coverage_count)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

I also did a quick Google search and could not find anything that exactly matches the term *coverage count*. **I am not an expert on the topic but I decided to give you my interpretation of the problem**. Given the final image, I believe you can think of *coverage count* as the number of non-black pixels, i.e. pixels that belong to one of the *relative/square* images. You can calculate those simply by gray-scaling the final image and counting the non-black pixels. If you are interested in a percentile representation, consider counting the black pixels and the total pixels in the image as well. Here are the values I got:

- Total pixels: 457650
- Non-black pixels: 381037
- Black pixels: 76613

You can further extend this approach and argue about the coverage of each relative image and perhaps even consider [@Marcus Müller](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/13320/marcus-m%C3%BCller)'s hint and argue how many images a single pixel maps to. I did not provide you with any code mostly because this question is part of an assignment, but also because you should be able to find the values yourself if you know how to blend images. Regardless, my hints should be enough for you if my logic is correct. I also up-voted your question as I am interested in finding out what this is exactly about. Hopefully, someone more experienced will be able to point you in the right direction if I did not.